# Openshift: How to obtain token for service account in java

Tags: java, authorization, openshift

I'm deploying my java application in openshift project. I have created service account, but now I dont know how to obtain token for this account inside my java application, that relates to this account.

I'm using `openshift java rest client v.6.1.1`. My authorization looks like

```
Client client = new ClientBuilder(KEY_SERVER_URL).build();
client.getAuthorizationContext().setToken(System.getenv(TOKEN));
```

and it seems unsecure to pass token as environment variable.

Can you help me with obtaining `AuthorizationContext` using service account, related to this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token for the service account is mounted inside the pod and can be read from `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

Comment: Some information about this in http://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-do-i-enable-rest-api-access-for-an-application.html

Comment: I tried to use authorize using this token from localhost and I couldn't. Do I need to create service account explicitly?

Comment: @SergeiPodlipaev what exactly did you do?

Comment: Used the token, specified in file to get authorization context (in java rest client)

Comment: Thanks, I used explicitly created service account and got the authorization context from this token.